# Image processing using C++ or go ahead with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a question for which I would like to learn from your experience at this point. I'm interested in implementing image processing algorithms along the way while learning them. Do you recommend me to do that with C++, or move ahead with OpenCV?

My goal is not to learn C++ per se, but to implement the image processing algorithms I learn.

What do you recommend me in this case? I don't want to start for instance with C++ and end up (maybe after a long learning curve) to the point where I have to deal with OpenCV eventually.

OpenCV is just an example, do you recommend it over other libraries for image processing?

Thanks for your recommendations.

Comment: just to give a second opinion, I recommend OpenCV, too.

Comment: since openCV is open source, maybe it makes sense to read a general image processing book like the one from Gonzalez and Woods and look at the implementation in openCV. I think there are two different things you could possibly learn: the algorithms themselves and implementation tricks.

Comment: I would suggest to implement the algorithms from scratch to really learn them and understand how they work. After that you can use OpenCV for applications, but imho OpenCV is quite badly written if you look at the source code.

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV is the perfect choice.

Don't reinvent the wheel. Don't implement your own limited, faulty image readers. Don't implement your own very basic data structures to store and access images in memory.

1. OpenCV 3.0 has a considerably clean and nice API. You can use high
   level C++ concepts with it. For example, you can work with STL-style
   iterators on matrices, which are also templated.
2. If you want to implement an algorithm yourself, you can work with
       the existing OpenCV codebase, maybe take something from there and
       change it. OpenCV has a permissive license.
3. If you feel like bringing GPU acceleration on board, OpenCV has it
       nicely integrated and you can start right away on a high level.
4. OpenCV is the de-facto standard in image processing and computer
   vision with C++. If you want to work with others in the field,
   chances are high that you are on common ground with OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. Do you recommend this book to start with OpenCV? Or, you have other recommendations? http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516130.do

Comment: @Simplicity that's quite old. I'd go with [online tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html)

Comment: The book came out *before* OpenCV 2.0 was released. Before version 2, OpenCV was C-only. So the book might still serve a purpose in explaining algorithms but not about how to write code using OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks all for your kind replies. I see your point now. Are there updated books you recommend? I came across this version of the book I mentioned, which seems to be coming soon: http://www.amazon.com/Learning-OpenCV-Computer-Vision-Library/dp/1491937998/ref=sr_1_11?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1439296633&sr=1-11&keywords=openCV Do you still recommend it?

Comment: I cannot comment on a book that I haven't seen. A book I really love is Digital Image Processing by Gonzalez and Woods. It is not about OpenCV or coding though.